# Percentile 25 as a DAX Measure on a combination weekDay & Hour

Tags: dax, grouping, percentile

I have a table in Power BI called Registration. The table has the following columns: timestamp, weekDay, Hour, condition, events. timestamp is the timestamp column, weekDay is the name of the day in the week like "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", etc. Hour has the hour of the events and Hour goes from 0 to 23. The 'condition' column has the following values: "Success", "Failed", and "Partial". 'events' column is of data type integer and hold the number of events at that Hour. The condition I am interested in is "Failed". But here is the tricky part: I want to calculate percentile 25 of every group combination of weekDay and Hour. Example: percentile 25 for all 'Tuesday' at Hour 16, and same way for all combinations weekDay & Hour. In summary, I want to write a Measure that calculate the percentile 25 of every combination of all groups of weekDay and Hour. Here below something I thought was easy but is not working:

```
Percentile 25 = 
    VAR failedEvents = 
        FILTER(Registration, Registration[condition] = "Failed")
    RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            PERCENTILEX.INC(failedEvents, Registration[Events], 0.25),
            GROUPBY(failedEvents, Registration[weekDay], Registration[Hour])
        )
    
Here below a sample in Kusto language.

let EventsData = datatable(Date:datetime, Event:long, weekDay: string, Hour: int ) [
    datetime(2022-11-29 00:00:00.0000000), 6, "Tuesday", 16,
    datetime(2022-12-06 00:00:00.0000000), 9, "Tuesday", 16,
    datetime(2022-12-13 00:00:00.0000000), 12, "Tuesday", 16,
    datetime(2022-12-20 00:00:00.0000000), 6, "Tuesday", 16,
    datetime(2022-12-27 00:00:00.0000000), 11, "Tuesday", 16,
    datetime(2023-01-03 00:00:00.0000000), 7, "Tuesday", 16
];
EventsData
| summarize percentiles(Event, 25, 50, 75)
| extend IQR = percentile_Event_75 - percentile_Event_25
| extend LT = percentile_Event_25 - 2 * IQR
| extend UT = percentile_Event_75 + 2 * IQR

The result should be:
percentile_Event_25 percentile_Event_50 percentile_Event_75 IQR LT UT
6                             7                 11           5  -4 21

Note: Added sample data and answer as per @DavidBacci request:

    
timestamp   weekDay Hour    condition   events
2022-09-09T11:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  8
2022-10-07T11:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  15
2022-10-14T11:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  16
2022-10-21T11:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  16
2022-10-28T11:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  16
2022-11-04T11:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  17
2022-11-11T12:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  25
2022-11-18T12:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  11
2022-12-02T12:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  9
2022-12-09T12:00:00Z    Friday  7   Failed  9


result must be:

weekDay    Hour    percentile_25    percentile_75
Friday  7   9   16


I greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Added sample data and required answer to the original question as per @DavidBacci suggestion. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this using Kusto. No need DAX for it. Here is how I resolved it.

```
Registration_Events
    | summarize reg_failed_summ = sum(reg_failed) by bin(timestamp, 1d), weekDay, Hour
    | summarize pcntls = percentiles_array(reg_failed_summ, 50, 25, 75) by weekDay, Hour
    | extend p50 = todouble(pcntls[0]), p25 = todouble(pcntls[1]), p75 = todouble(pcntls[2])
    | extend IQR = p75 - p25
    | extend LT = p25 - 2 * IQR, UT = p75 + 2 * IQR
    | extend LT = iif(LT <= 0, real(null), LT)
    | project weekDay, Hour, LT, p25, IQR, p75, UT
```